# Vue js how to add component to cell in table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to add a component(a dropdown list that fetch the options from the database)...

```
export default {
  name: 'IngMenu',
  props:['ingredients'],
  data () {
    return {
      selected: '',
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement('select', 
      this.$props.ingredients.map(function(ing){
        return createElement('option', ing.name)
      })
    )

  }
}
```

into a cell/row generated with a button

```
<button class="btn" id="add" v-on:click="addRow">Add Ingredient</button>
```

here the method...

```
methods: {
    addRow: function(){
        let table = document.getElementById("tab");
        let row = table.insertRow();
        let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        let cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell1.appendChild(document.createElement('Ingmenu')); //ERROR
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        cell5.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

}
```

}
}

the component works perfectly if i add it t the top of the page but i cannot insert inside the cell.

What i have tryied so far:

**cell1.innerHtml = ""** it add the  tag in the table tree instead of rendering the component

**cell1.appendChild(document.createElement('Ingmenu'));** it does the same as above

**cell1.innerText** obviusly it display the tag as text

As i said above the component is been initialized correctly and works on any page as long as it can access the ingredients prop.

i have lost almoast a day trying to figure it  out alone.

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks for the interest

Comment: Why... are you using DOM manipulation to create a Vue component? Let Vue render the table.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean. Are you refering to Vue grid component? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of Vue is allowing your "view" (the DOM or HTML if you will) be a representation of your data.

There is almost never a reason in Vue for you to be directly manipulating the DOM using `getElementById` or `appendChild`.

Instead, write your template in the fashion in which you would *expect* it to be laid out based on some data structure. In this case, you are adding "rows". Rows of *what* I have no idea, but somewhere there should be a collection of *things*. When you want to add a row to your table, just add a new *thing* to the collection and Vue will take care of adding it to the DOM.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const IngMenu = {
  name: 'IngMenu',
  props:['ingredients'],
  data () {
    return {
      selected: '',
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement('select', 
      this.$props.ingredients.map(function(ing){
        return createElement('option', ing.name)
      })
    )

  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    rows:[],
    ingredients: [{name: "One"}, {name: "Two"}]
  },
  methods: {
    addRow(){
      // Push some real data object here that represents 
      // what each row "is"
      this.rows.push({})
    }
  },
  components: {IngMenu}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td>
        <ing-menu :ingredients="ingredients"></ing-menu>
      </td>
      <td>NEW CELL2</td>
      <td>NEW CELL3</td>
      <td>NEW CELL4</td>
      <td>NEW CELL5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="btn" id="add" v-on:click="addRow">Add Ingredient</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code works perfectly, i will need to create a row component as this is part of larger app. The only tthink i don't really understand is when you push an empty object to the rows array and a new row gets created. I do understand the v-for part, is how it gets ceated from addRow() that i don't understand. Could you please explain this? Thanks again

Comment: @FraPetIm Again, this goes back to the fact that a table is a representation of a *collection* of things. In the answer above, that collection is called `rows`. I don't know what things *you* want to display in the table, but you have *some* things. For the sake of the example, I made that collection of things a collection of empty objects. `v-for="row in rows"` just displays each row in the `rows` collection. Every time you click the button, a new empty object is added to the collection, so you get a new row. In a typical application, when you click addRow, you would add one of your *things*.